# Displaying For-Loop progress without heavily affecting performance in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Lets say I have a for loop like this (ignore the terrible efficiency, this is just an example):

```
ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
  if(isPrime(i)){
    primes.add(i);
  }
}
```

I want to display the progress of the loop at every interval of 10%, however I don't know how to do this without affecting the performance. This is all I can think of so far:

```
ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
int n = 10000/10;
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
  if(isPrime(i)){
    primes.add(i);
  }
  if(i == n){
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(i).charAt(0)+"0% Complete");
    n+=10000/10;
  }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Are you missing a parentheses on the if statement? Just pointing that out :)

Comment: 90% of questions like this about performance and efficiency are premature.  How have you determined that you have a performance problem and how has this been measured?  If performance is "good enough" for your purpose, then no more time or money needs to be spent.

Comment: Is **i.isPrime()** work? I think primitive does not have methods.

Comment: @scottb What about a case where I'll be doing over 500 billion iterations for a monte-carlo type solution?

Comment: @ZinMinn No, isPrime() isn't a native method in Java. It was just an example.

Comment: So, you should use like **isPrime(i)**

Comment: maybe do the work on a separate thread and then asynchronously report progress back to the ui thread. you can do this with a SwingWorker.

Comment: @Arman: Well, if you had data that, with your present implementation, your program spent less than 5% of its time in your progress reporting code, then how important would you feel that it is to spend time and coding effort to decrease that to, say, less than 2%?  Without profiling performance, you don't even know that you have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a fan of this approach:

```
ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
final int I_MAX = 10_000; final int N_MAX = I_MAX / 10;
for (int i = 0, n = 10; i < I_MAX; i++, n++, n %= N_MAX) {
    if (i.isPrime()) primes.add(i);
    if (n == 0) System.out.println((i / (I_MAX / 10)) + "0% complete");
}
```

You can also do something like this, which doesn't involve tracking another variable:

```
ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
final int I_MAX = 10_000;
for (int i = 0; i < I_MAX; i++) {
    if (i.isPrime()) primes.add(i);
    if (i % (I_MAX / 10) == 0) System.out.println((i / (I_MAX / 10)) + "0% complete");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clean solution!

Comment: @Arman You're welcome! You can probably eke a little more performance out of both by making judicious use of temporary variables and stuff like that, but ultimately both of these have very little overhead, as do most solutions. The real meat of the delay is going to come from your equivalent of `if (i.isPrime()) primes.add(i);`. I'd suggest focusing on that if you need further speed reduction, and only then coming back to this kind of thing.

Comment: `if (i % (I_MAX / 10) == 0) System.out.println(i / 10 + "0% complete");` when `i == 9000` - what will this print?

Comment: @Scary Er, whoops. That's a typo. I'm on mobile at the moment, could you fix it for me?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Fixed, probably. I don't have a Java compiler available at the moment to test.

Answer (score 5):

I've found that hardcoding the step value (e.g. 10% increments) when printing progress is not that useful. It's better to print/update progress every X (milli)seconds, so you can see actual progress all the time.

If your logic is slow enough to need progress, the performance impact of printing progress is minuscule, and seeing a good progress value will make it feel faster.

So, to update progress at time intervals, do something like this:

```
final long count = 1_000_000_000L;
long nextTime = 0;
for (long i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (time >= nextTime) {
        System.out.printf("%.2f%%\r", i * 100d / count);
        nextTime = time + 200;
    }
    // slowMethod();
}
System.out.println("100.00%");
```

Since I didn't have a "slowMethod", I simply increased the iteration count to be slow enough to see progress.

The `200` value means that it'll print progress every 200ms, i.e. 5 times a second. You can increase the value if you think that's too much, but I like it.

Printing the progress using `\r` means that the progress is updated on a single line. That works fine if running from a Windows command prompt, but IDE's (e.g. Eclipse) may just treat it as a newline, printing each progress update on a new line in the Console pane, in which case frequent updates are less desirable.

Comment: Nice - will add to my toolbox

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
int n = 10000/10;
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
  if(i.isPrime()){
    primes.add(i);
  }
  if((i+1) % n == 0){
    System.out.println((i+1)/n*10 + "% Complete");
  }
}
```

This does not print at 0% though, but I think similar concept can do the job.

The performance definitely won't be affected much as you only add a constant time factor in each iteration.

Answer (score -3):

Use a nested for loop. You'll note this answer has only one comparison per iteration instead of two.

```
ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println("0% Complete");
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  for(int j=0; j<1000;j++){
    if(i.isPrime()){
      primes.add(i);
    }
  }
  System.out.println(i+"0% Complete");
}
System.out.println("100% Complete");
```

Comment: You are only testing the primness of 0-9